# OH-SCM-009: Error occurred while sync. TF14059: Unable to process the pending changes requested

Tags: azure-devops, opshub

Using OpsHub VS Online migration tool version 1.1.0.005

Getting error: OH-SCM-009: Error occurred while sync. TF14059: Unable to process the pending changes requested. The set of pending renames would cause a name collision.

Looking at the change set, it looks like a file is listed as a "Delete/Rename" change.

Can provide logs if needed.

Comment: Can you please send us your logs located at <installation-path>/logs to ovsmu@opshub.com for analyze further.

Comment: Jake, was @Opshub able to help you with this? We're experiencing the same issue.